# how to project field in array with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

my collection in mongo db like this:

```
{
    name:"mehdi",
    grades:
        [
            {
                a:1,
                b:[2,3,4],
                c:3,
                d:4,
                e:5
            },
            {
                a:11,
                b:[22,33,44],
                c:33,
                d:44,
                e:55
            }
         ]
}
```

I want to get a result with project op to give me a specific field in an array like this:

```
{
    name:"mehdi",
    grades:
        [
            {
                a:1,
                b:2
            },
            {
                a:11,
                b:22
            }
         ]
}
```

how can I do this?

Comment: You can use `find` query [projection operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/) _and_ [aggregation array operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#array-expression-operators) for projecting array fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to select `a,b` fields using [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) to determine whether it's an `array` or number:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            grades: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$grades",
                    in: {
                        a: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ { $type: "$$this.a" }, "array" ] }, { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$this.a", 0 ] }, "$$this.a" ] },
                        b: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ { $type: "$$this.b" }, "array" ] }, { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$this.b", 0 ] }, "$$this.b" ] },
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yK1wORIN8nk)